# Where does QModelIndex() come from in seekRoot.parent() != QModelIndex();

Tags: c++, qt, model-view

In Qt help, there is an example in Model/View Tutorial - 3.2 Working with Selections. The resource codes are in *Qt\Qt5.9.1\Examples\Qt-5.9.1\widgets\tutorials\modelview\7_selections*.

I cannot understand what is [QModelIndex()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html#QModelIndex) in `while(seekRoot.parent() != QModelIndex())`.
It looks like a constructor of QModelIndex, but what's the usage here? It returns a new empty model index? Or it is a function of MainWindow? It seems impossible.

Where does it come from? And what is the return value?

```
void MainWindow::selectionChangedSlot(const QItemSelection & /*newSelection*/, const QItemSelection & /*oldSelection*/)
{
    //get the text of the selected item
    const QModelIndex index = treeView->selectionModel()->currentIndex();
    QString selectedText = index.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
    //find out the hierarchy level of the selected item
    int hierarchyLevel=1;
    QModelIndex seekRoot = index;
    while(seekRoot.parent() != QModelIndex())
    {
        seekRoot = seekRoot.parent();
        hierarchyLevel++;
    }
    QString showString = QString("%1, Level %2").arg(selectedText)
                         .arg(hierarchyLevel);
    setWindowTitle(showString);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The empty [`QModelIndex()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html#QModelIndex) constructor indicates an invalid (i.e. non existing) `QModelIndex`:

> Creates a new empty model index. This type of model index is used to
> indicate that the position in the model is invalid.

So `seekRoot.parent() != QModelIndex()` checks if `seekRoot` has a parent (i.e. its parent is not invalid).

It could also be written (more clearly) as `seekRoot.parent().isValid()` (see [`QModelIndex::isValid`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html#isValid)).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `isValid`. It's WAY more readable than `!= QModelIndex()`.

Answer (score 3):

The default constructor `QModelIndex()` creates a temporary invalid index the output of `seekRoot.parent()` call compared with. In other words, this expression checks whether the parent index is valid or not.